# Running command line for kubectl image in yaml for k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to declare in yaml file command line that uses the kubectl image, for any command of `kubectl', i.e. waiting to another pod to be for ready state.

If I run in command:

```
kubectl wait pod/mypod --for=condition=ready --timeout=120s
```

I get a true message of:

> pod/mypod condition met

First - How to run the command prompt, for simple use?

i.e use of `kubectl version`, so the output, is the version of the kube, for using the image: kubectl:

```
kubectl run test -it --rm --image=bitnami/kubectl get pods --restart=Never --command -- 
/bin/kubectl version
```

(I want to run once, and delete the pod automatically when it ends. Same thing for the command: `kubectl wait pod/mypod --for=condition=ready --timeout=120s` or any command uses kubectl image).

The above doesn't work.

Also - how should I convert the above to kubernetes yaml file (one time run - when it completed, the pod will be deleted automatically) ?

The following doesn't work, when I am waiting, i.e. for mypod to complete.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: wait-for-pod
          image: bitnami/kubectl
          args:
            - wait
            - pod/mypod
            - --for=condition=ready
            - --timeout=120s
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: myapp
```

Has the status: `Init:ContainerCannotRun`.

and when I run: `kubectl describe pod <mypod>`, I get the message:

`OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "wait": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `kubectl run` command is wrong. The `--image=bitnami/kubectl get pods` part is incorrect. You need to specify just the image, not the command.
Proper, working command would be

```text
kubectl run test -it --rm --image=bitnami/kubectl --restart=Never -- version
```

When it comes to the Deployment manifest, you were almost there. Just add `command` list to the manifest, and it should work.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: wait-for-pod
          image: bitnami/kubectl
          command:
            - kubectl
          args:
            - wait
            - --for=condition=Ready
            - pod/mypod
            - --timeout=120s
      containers:
        - name: myapp
          image: myapp
```

---

Now, you need to remember, `system:serviceaccount:default:default` service account, which is attached to every pod, does not have sufficient priviledges to list pods in cluster. All of the above **wil not work** unless you give *default* service account proper priviledges

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: service-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["services"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: service-reader-pod
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: service-reader
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Comment: Found that also, after "digging" for hours. Thank you very much!!!